# How to get updated end location for a Uber Ride?

Tags: uber-api

I am using Uber's webhooks to trigger retrieving ride information using uber API. Although if the ride's destination changes when the ride is in progress, I don't get a hook callback. And once the ride is completed, the start and destination information is not available in ride details.
Is there a way to get this information (rather than keep polling the API every few seconds?)

Answer (score 0):

You should receive the location information in the 'in_progress' webhook. We do not currently fire event if destination changes so the only way to discover is to poll the /requests/current end point. Uber API will not return the final location after the trip has been completed or via the history endpoint (though you can see the pickup location).

Comment: The history information just gives following information:
    {
      "status": "completed",
      "distance": 2.4445998557,
      "product_id": "a1111c8c-c720-46c3-8534-2fcdd730040d",
      "start_time": 1474685017,
      "start_city": {
        "latitude": 37.7749,
        "display_name": "San Francisco",
        "longitude": -122.4194
      },
      "end_time": 1474685568,
      "request_id": "81a0ffda-a879-4443-beb8-e253f4d19ecc",
      "request_time": 1474684872
    }

Comment: And the completed webhook gives this much information only:
{"event_id":"0dc5e0ac-17b3-454c-ae5f-fe5d2b04cef1","event_time":1481262644,"event_type":"requests.status_changed","meta":{"user_id":"cc6d1d2b-ddd7-4484-8a59-dcd45ab339fe","resource_id":"a47e1528-8166-4e66-a17a-4a4cca2059ef","status":"completed"},"resource_href":"https://sandbox-api.uber.com/v1/requests/a47e1528-8166-4e66-a17a-4a4cca2059ef"}

Neither the API or the Hook provides the destination information.

Comment: Correct. I have updated my answer to reflect. This information is only included in the in_progress webhook or via /requests/current.

Comment: Ok, is there any specific reason why we can't get the information in a completed request? Because the information is surely in the data store.